# List.equals is false despite all objects in list being equal

Tags: java, list, equals

I have a list of objects, say `Article`, which is quite a complex, nested object. I will omit the actual class as it shouldn't matter really; it is probably important to know that `Article` has `equals()` implemented (with AutoValue).

I have two lists:

```
List<Article> list1 = getSomeArticles(); 
List<Article> list2 = getOtherArticles();
```

Now I check if they are equal:

```
boolean listsAreEqual = list1.equals(list2);
```

this returns `false`. 
But I check if a. both lists have the same size and b. each item at index `i` is equal in both lists:

```
if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
  return; 
}

for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
  Article article1 = list1.get(i);
  Article article2 = list2.get(i); 

  if (!article1.equals(article2)) {
    return; 
  }
}

// All items in the two lists are equals, but list2.equals(list2) is false
```

Both lists seem to contain exactly the same items, but list1.equals(list2) returns `false`.

How can that be?

Comment: @Michael Good catch! Was a typo though.

Comment: @Michael Fixed that too, thanks.

Comment: Any sensible `List` implementation will implement `equals` exactly the same way that you have - by iterating over the elements. You are asking us to effectively explain a paradox, when the far more likely reason for your problem is that `Article.equals` is not implemented properly.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]!

Comment: What `List` implementation is used by `getSomeArticles` and `getOtherArticles`? Shouldn't matter but I'm grasping at straws.

Comment: My best guess given the limited information that you've given us is that you're using some implementation of `List` which does the opposite equality check (i.e. `article2.equals(article1)`) - and I'm not aware of any in the JDK that do - and that your `Article.equals` method is not symmetric.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I'd love to, but I can't post all the related code, that would be dozens of classes, and I can't re-create a simple example that exhibits the same problem. 
I though maybe there's some quirk to this that I don't know of.

Comment: @asco Then put a breakpoint in the `equals` method of `Article`. We can't help you.

Comment: @asco you'll likely find the problem when trying to create an MCVE by removing extraneous things.

Comment: @Michael Seems like. I know the question is pretty useless since people can't reproduce it, but I though maybe someone had an idea. Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be equal. Something is not right with your code. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns
>   true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists
>   have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two
>   lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ?
>   e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to
>   be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This
>   definition ensures that the equals method works properly across
>   different implementations of the List interface.

Unless, of course, the `List` implementation overrides the default from `java.util.List`.

Comment: Yeah, I though so too. 
I'll check my code again (I can't post the complete original here because of proprietarity etc) ...

Comment: Can you let us know what implementation of list was used?